# PySpark - Sum a column, cast to decimal and rename it

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, sum

i have a pyspark dataframe with a column of numbers and want to sum, cast and rename it:

```
simpleData = (("Java",4000,5), \
    ("Python", 4600,10),  \
    ("Scala", 4100,15),   \
    ("Scala", 4500,15),   \
    ("PHP", 3000,20),  \
  )
columns= ["name", "nondiscountedmarketvalue", "discount %"]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

I tried something like this:

```
df.select('name',
          df.select(sum(df['nondiscountedmarketvalue'].cast('decimal (18,2)')).alias('sum_marketvalue')))
```

but then i recieved an error saying 'TypeError: Column is not iterable'.

Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: Using nested `selects` might be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
df.select(sum(df.nondiscountedmarketvalue).cast(DecimalType(18,2)).alias('sum_marketvalue')).show()
```

You'll need the following imports.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType
```